# Avoiding inline with Kotlin generics

Tags: java, generics, kotlin, jackson, jackson-databind

I'm trying to build a generic class for handling configuration injections in Kotlin and Java.

Basically I want a class to be bound to a data class and a path to a resource file that should contain an easily writable deserialization of an instance of the data class.

What I have come up with so far is this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.jacksonObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.readValue

class ResourceLoader()

inline fun <reified T : Any> loadObject(resourcePath: String): T {
    // Load resource file
    val resource = ResourceLoader::class.java.classLoader.getResource(resourcePath)
    val resourceContent = resource.readText()

    // Return deserialized object
    return jacksonObjectMapper().readValue(resourceContent)
}


abstract class ResourceBound<T : Any>(val resourcePath: String) {
    inline fun <reified U : T> getResource(): U {
        return loadObject(this.resourcePath)
    }
}
```

With this, I can bind a test class to the existence of a resource file, and have it fail in glorious *exception*ality if the file is missing of malformed, like so:

```
data class ServiceConfig(val endpoint: String, val apiKey: String)

class TestClassLoadingConfig() : ResourceBound<ServiceConfig>("TestConfig.json") {
    @Test
    fun testThis() {
        val config: ServiceConfig = this.getResource()
        val client = ServiceClient(config.endpoint, config.apiKey)
        ...
    }
}
```

Only problem is that it only works in Kotlin because `inline` is not compatible with java. So how do I get around this?

As a bonus, I would like to get rid of the explicit type declaration so `val config: ServiceConfig = this.getResource()` can just be `val config = this.getResource()`.

Comment: You can use an unchecked cast instead, e.g. just writing `return jacksonObjectMapper().readValue(resourceContent) as T`.

Comment: Then I get `Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead.` if I use the Kotlin'ized `jacksonObjectMapper()`. If I instead try `ObjectMapper().readValue(resource, object : TypeReference<T>() {}) as T`, I get a runtime exception: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to dk.whatever...`

Comment: sorry, my mistake... when un/marshalling you need a concrete type... which is what you delivered also with the `TypeReference<T>() {}`... at least I thought so... if you just pass the type itself (e.g. `dk.whatever.....class`), does it work then?

Comment: Nope. I'm trying to code this in Java instead now, and the I will see if it works in Kotlin.

Comment: This looks more and more like a limitation of Jackson. My Java implementation also results in `ClassCastException`

Comment: I will leave this question as is for now. Unfortunately I deleted my java implementation, so I cannot share it. For now, I'm going simple on this; instead of deserializing to a custom class, i will always deserialize to a `Map<String, String>`.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same issue recently, and solved it by passing along a `TypeReference` as a second parameter.

My base config class:

```
package config

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinModule

open class BaseConfig<T>(configFile: String, typeReference: TypeReference<T>) {

    val config: T

    init {
        val mapper = ObjectMapper(YAMLFactory())
        mapper.registerModule(KotlinModule())

        val inputStream = this.javaClass.classLoader
            .getResourceAsStream(configFile)
        config = mapper.readValue(inputStream, typeReference)
    }
}
```

Example data class:

```
package config.dto

data class MessageDto(
    val `example messages`: List<String>
)
```

Example object:

```
package config

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference
import config.dto.MessageDto

object Message: BaseConfig<MessageDto>("messages.yml", object: TypeReference<MessageDto>() {}) {
    val exampleMessages: List<String> = config.`example messages`
}
```

Example yaml:

```
example messages:
  - "An example message"
  - "Another example message"
```

It's not as concise as I would have wished, but it works, and it gives me a flexible way to map content from config files to any data class.